# package not found in main

Tags: go, go-modules

Im using go modules to make a new go project.  I have my main project in a dir path MyDocuments/Mygoapp. It contains the main package with func main(). I also created another package in the path MyDocuments/ShareGo. This package is called commoncode. It has functions I would like to call in the main.go file from my main package. My main.go is not able to see the commoncode package. What do I have to add to my go.mod in the main package to the commoncode package? Before I had both projects in my GOPATH and it worked.

Comment: Typically go.mod is generated by go during build. But, you are facing the issue because you are using private modules. Check this article that describes how to set this up. https://medium.com/@tim_raymond/fetching-private-dependencies-with-go-modules-1d65afe47c62

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is required in go.mod. You use an `import` statement in main.go. You may need to set your `GOPATH` environment variable. Go look at the documentation for GOPATH and imports.

Comment: HenryTK. My go path is set. If I have both  Mygoapp and ShareGo folders in my go path it works with modules off. Im trying to use go modules